# Qt -- how to call void virtual functions in Qt

Tags: qt, virtual

I am quite new to Qt project as well as to C++ and I am wondering how would I call virtual functions with the object. For example with QPushbutton  object I can able to call public functions directly but cant able to call virtual void functions? Does it mean that I need to implement those functions in my code before I can use it. Can anyone able to give me quick example of how to call virtual function with the object.

Thanks

Comment: read some book about basics of C++ (it is not qt issue). Any book for beginners should solve your problem.

Comment: Which virtual function of `QPushButton` class wasn't you able to call?

Comment: public/private/protected and virtual/non-virtual are orthogonal. You can call any public functions from outside the class, no matter if virtual or not.